# How to start Node Js server on each system boot in Mac and windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Mac book and whenever I  restart my PC I need to run script again to start mode js server. How can I automate it so that I will not need to run sever script again to start local node js server ?

Comment: if you're using a "mac book" what does that have to do with Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install `pm2` package as global with:

```
npm i -g pm2
```

and in project directory run

```
pm2 start index.js
```

`index.js` is your starter file. for e.g. `server.js`, `main.js` anything can be

add finally run the following command for start them at boot

```
pm2 startup
```

Comment: No such file or directory found ... coming on terminal

Comment: You can change it to the correct location or file name and use it.

Comment: The command produced by pm2 startup causes the os to look for a file at `/Users/[username]/Library/LaunchAgents/...`

It should be looking in `/Library/LaunchAgents/...`

Could you explain how to change the path please?

Comment: You can look for solutions in the following links

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs